# Clearing and adding list using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an xml file with the data below:

```
<ConfigurationEntries>
  <ConfigurationUpdates enabled="false">
    <ListOfValues>
      <add id="1" />
      <add id="2" />
      <add id="3" />
    </ListOfValues>
  </ConfigurationUpdates>
</ConfigurationEntries>
```

I would like to remove the entries under `ListOfValues` and add one single entry there: `<add id="100" />`

So far, I have this:

```
<xsl:template match="/ConfigurationEntries/ConfigurationUpdates/ListOfValues">
   <xsl:copy>
      <clear />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      // Not sure what goes here.
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Well that depends on what you want in there! The first `apply-templates` does nothing as the `ListOfValues` elements has no attributes. You have inserted an empty `clear` element. Then what would you like in place of the three `add` elements?

Comment: Ah, I see you had a chunk of XML that wasn't showing up because you didn't add markup. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
<xsl:template match="/ConfigurationEntries/ConfigurationUpdates/ListOfValues">
   <xsl:copy>
      <clear />
      <add id="100" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But I am not sure what the empty `clear` element is doing there as you don't mention it. Did you think it did something in the XSLT? All that happens is that it is copied to the output.

Comment: Actually, I just checked, 'Clear' did not do anything. :( Any other way of clearing the list?

Comment: There is nothing sent to the output unless you ask for it to be sent. Just remove `<clear />` from my solution and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help you.

```
<xsl:template match="/ConfigurationEntries/ConfigurationUpdates/ListOfValues">
    <ListOfValues>
        <add id="100" />
    </ListOfValues>
</xsl:template>
```